# google sheets formatting pasting array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, numbers, format

I have a script that gets information from an API and writes it to google sheets. In the data from the API the numbers all look normal but once written to google sheets they are all changed. for example 4319.05 is written back as 4319:05:00.000.
When I try to format the range after its been pasted to the sheet I get really strange results where 4319:05:00.000 formatted as number, gives the value of 179.96.

The API can be found at:
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

The code used is as follows:

```
    function getCoinMarketCapAPI() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    Logger.log(sheets)

    var url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"; 

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
    var dataSet = dataAll;
    Logger.log(dataSet)
    var rows = [],
    data;
    Logger.log(rows)

    for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
     rows.push([data.id,data.name,data.symbol,data.rank,data.price_usd,data.price_btc,data.percent_change_1h,data.percent_change_24h,data.percent_change_7d,data.last_updated]);
    }

dataRange = sheet.getRange(6, 1, rows.length, 10); 
dataRange.setValues(rows);


}
```

Any help would be so appreciated! =)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script worked fine for the numbers. I did have to fix the date. Format for my sheet is automatic.

```
  function getCoinMarketCapAPI() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"; 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dataSet = dataAll;
  var rows = [],data;
  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  data = dataSet[i];
  var d=new Date(data.last_updated*1000)// convert to date
 rows.push([data.id,data.name,data.symbol,data.rank,data.price_usd,data.price_btc,data.percent_change_1h,data.percent_change_24h,data.percent_change_7d,d]);
}
dataRange = sheet.getRange(6, 1, rows.length, 10); 
dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

Here is my test spreadsheet you can copy and try.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dg2opJG3NEc_Ud5MrXnuFplDXnVoO9_ul-QW_MczWZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's so strange!! Format for my sheet was also automatic. Heres what I got:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zR-XuUOwG6KrjJFwcWZfkGkhBe5Hnnvy0ObLZEaiTAc/pubhtml

Comment: Probably a setting somewhere or something. A big thank you for taking the time and sorting out the date formatting! =)

Brian

Comment: Figured out what was causing the problem. I Feel so stupid that I didn't check but my language settings where set to Swedish and this caused the weird number-format.. I thought there was something wrong with my script.. 

Again, Big Thanks!